# send data from activity to another without starting activity or how to refresh TextView

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to know how to pass data from one activity via intents without starting the activity. I'm using TabViews and when I start the other Activity, I loose my TabView and TabIcons because I use MainActivity.tabHost.setCurrentTab(2); to switch between Tabs.

```
btnShowResult.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {    
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            result = database.getResult();
            MainActivity.tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
        }
    });
```

I defined a global variable result and fill it with a value from my database, when clicking on the Button. It loads my 3rd Tab, where I call txtView.setText(SecondTab.result+"");

This works fine when I click the button for the first time. But changing the variable result has no effect on txtView since it's not refreshed.

How can I refresh the txtView after changing the global var result? Calling ThirdTab.txtView.invalidate(); in the onClick-Function causes my app to crash.

Thanks.

---

EDIT:

Alright. I did it with SharedPreferences by saving my result into the sharedPrefs and loading from it in the second Tab. However the showed result in my txtView is still the same and doesn't change. Where and how do I tell my second Tab to refresh the txtView after my result in sharedPrefs have changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works now, although it's not so nice code:

```
public static int hasChanged = 0;
...
btnShowResult.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {    
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            result = database.getResult();
            if (hasChanged != 0)
                Tab3.txtView.setText(result+"");

            MainActivity.tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
        }
    });
```

And in my 3rd Tab after creating and drawing the txtView I set the global variable hasChanged to 1, so that now everytime after clicking on the Button btnShowResult, the txtView is set to the new value of result.

Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your data needed in shared preferences and then you can access it from any activity, so you don't need to pass it via intent and using start activity

```
 http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/01/example-of-using-sharedpreferencesedito.html

 http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html

 http://alchemiaandroid.altervista.org/sharedPreferencesTutorial.html
```

Above links are tutorial examples for using shared preferences.
 Saving data as (Key,value) pairs and then you can access the value you want by its key

Answer (score 0):

What if you just invoke `txtView.setText(result)` again ?

Comment: but how and where? When I call it within my onClick-Function, it crashes again

Answer (score 0):

The Best way to maintain the values until kill the app is Shared Preferences.
So, follow this link to storing and getting  the values from shared preferences
http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html

Comment: I tried this but there are still no changes in my TextView after the first time loading it. However, when I close the app and reopen it, the value changes, but again just once after pressing the button